# In APACHE SQOOP how to find maximum and minimum values

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

My data

table name: emp

```
1,javeed,10000
2,raghava,20000
3,zakeer,35000
4,nag,22000
5,Akhil,75000
6,raghava,25000
```

i want to find maxium and minimum value in sqoop,

Comment: Sqoop doesn't return data... It moves entire tables

Answer (score 2):

You can find the min and max values using `sqoop eval` it will print in the console but it doesn't import.

```
sqoop eval \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db \
--username root \ 
--query “SELECT min(col1), max(col1) from someschem.sometable”
```

If you just want to store the min and max values in some file redirect the above sqoop jobs output to a file. Something like below.

```
sqoop eval \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/db \
    --username root \ 
    --query “SELECT min(col1), max(col1) from someschem.sometable” >> /path/Yourfile.txt
```

Use Awk or Sed in Unix to filter out the unwanted stack produced by sqoop into the output file.